# Johansen cointegration test - vector directions?

Tags: python

I'm performing a rolling Johansen test for cointegration across three time series in order to obtain an online/evolving eigentvector at each new timestep. I'm using the .coint_johansen() implementation from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.

My question is why the vector element sometimes switch signs? The rolling window for the Johansen calculation is 20 000 minutes and the absolute amount of the element values evolve ever so slowly. Hence it would be extremely unlikely that the eigenvectors would "turn backwards" from one minute to the next. The graph shows the first element of the roling eigenvector. I need to get the continuous values without the occasional sign reversals.

Why does this happen and is there any convenient way to consistently orient the eigenvector output of the coint_johansen()?

```
2018-10-31 17:20:00 [-0.01669008  0.02542677 -0.09270737]
2018-10-31 17:21:00 [-0.01677716  0.02543248 -0.09265081]
2018-10-31 17:22:00 [ 0.01684433 -0.02543571  0.09261844]
2018-10-31 17:23:00 [-0.01675599  0.02543448 -0.09266106]
2018-10-31 17:24:00 [-0.01676379  0.02543654 -0.09265483]
2018-10-31 17:25:00 [ 0.01689747 -0.02544224  0.09258631]
2018-10-31 17:26:00 [ 0.01697933 -0.02544516  0.0925532 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both eigenvector-orientations are valid. If you want consistency, you can simply divide all components of an eigenvector by the sign of the first component.